# Is possible to write a trait to detect a friend class declaration?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, friend, detection-idiom

I would like to know if it is possible to write a trait capable to detect a friend class declaration. I'm particularly interested in the case of forward declaration, like so:

```
struct Baz
{
   friend struct Foo; 
};

struct Foo {};
```

Please no Boost or other external libraries. The answer should stick either with the standard (C++17) or a custom trait.

Comment: What would you do with this ability? It doesn't seem reasonable to SFINAE something around such a construct.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm writing a reflection library based on template metaprogramming. In order to allow the reflection system to inspect a type (within its private member) a friend declaration must be done: 
`template <typename T>
friend struct reflection::ReflectedTypeInternal
`
I would like to detect if that friend declaration is present in order to eventually throw compile time errors and ease the use of the library.

Comment: Wouldn't you throw a compile error when you try and fail to reflect into the type?

Comment: @NicolBolas I do that already. But detecting that friend declaration would allow me to throw better readable errors in early stages of the compilation. Otherwise I have to rely in later stages compilation errors which are less understandables.

Comment: You could create a helper macro which generates this friend declaration and also some hidden tag type, which you can detect later. I don't think you can detect the friend itself.